# Best models to determine the impact of demographic variables on chances of winning a competition?

Tags: econometrics, stata

I have a dataset where **two teams generally compete against each other**. For each team, I've gathered **demographic characteristics** such as the percentage of males, the number of males, average age, percentage of whites, and the number of whites, along with **a binary variable** (1 or 0) indicating whether a team won a competition.

I'm interested in understanding how these variables might influence **a team's chances of winning a competition**. I've already implemented a **probit** model as the most straightforward approach.

Do you have any other suggestions for models that could serve as **robustness checks**? One idea I had was to incorporate distance measures, such as measuring the "maleness," age, and "whiteness" distances, applying z-scores, and then running a probit analysis again. **Are there any other models you recommend?**

Comment: What diagnostics have you run for the model?  Why do you feel that a robustness check is required?  What conclusion are you trying to draw from the new model?

Comment: Sorry I was trying not to overflow my original post. I did not run any sort of diagnostics, just ran what seemed the most pertinent given the data, as preliminary analyses. I feel that robustness checks are required as I found some weak evidence that skin color impact chances of winning whereas, it should not (in my views at least). I am trying to test how robust this finding is... 
To be more precise, those are the team competitions data from the TV game show The Survivor. Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: The first step to understanding how robustly a statistical model performs is to run fit diagnostics.  There are plenty of textbooks that explain what to check for a generalized linear model like a probit model.  If you determine that the probit model does not fit well or does not conform to the model assumptions, then you should switch to a more robust model or take some other action.  Generally, it is not a good idea to fit more models to check the first model when you don't know if any of the fits are any good.

Comment: Thank you @RCarnell, I will do.